# Use jackson annotation on a field to be the root for deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson, annotations

I have a class that I want to deserialize to:

```
@Data
public class Config {

    private Map<String, Item> items;
}

@Data
public class Item {

    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
}
```

JSON string:

```
{
  "item1": {
    "a": "1",
    "b": "2",
    "c": "3"
  },
  "item2": {
    "a": "10",
    "b": "20",
    "c": "30"
  },
  "item3": {
    "a": "5",
    "b": "6",
    "c": "7"
  }
}
```

What should I use to deserialize the JSON string into Config?

EDIT: Added more items to JSON

Comment: `items` and `item1` is not matching

Comment: Don't use `HashMap` on the declaration side, it is a bad practise. Rather use `Map`

Comment: Can you show `Item` class? has only String field as property?

Comment: Using Map and I added Item class.

Answer (score 1):

A coworker helped me with this answer to my question:

```
@Data
public class Config {

    private Map<String, Item> items;

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Item> getItems() {
       return items;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setItem(final String key, final Item value) {
       items.put(key, value);
    }
}

@Data
public class Item {

    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Use [JsonAlias](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) to get multiple values in single property:

```
@JsonAlias({"item1", "item2", "item3"})
private Map<String, Item> items;
```

> Annotation that can be used to define one or more alternative names for a property

**Older answer to old question**

Add [JsonProperty](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) with name `item1`

```
@Data
public class Config {
    @JsonProperty("item1")
    private Map<String, Item> items;
}
```

> Marker annotation that can be used to define a non-static method as a "setter" or "getter" for a logical property (depending on its signature), or non-static object field to be used (serialized, deserialized) as a logical property.

**EDIT**

Updated as `Map` following @michaeak comment

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I should have made the example clearer. There are multiple items.